# Resque workers dying silently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

I'm having issues with the workers that I have set up for a website. Here's Some background of the app:
It runs on rails 3.0.2, using mongodb, redis gem 2.2.2. In order to keep the workers up and running I have set up the god gem and specify that 6 workers should run in the production environment. I'll be pasting the resque.god.rb file bellow. Also, there's a unique Ubuntu server that is set up for the resque-workers and elasticsearch services only so it doesn't share any other service.

My problem is that for any reason, the workers keep dying and just log "***Exiting..." in my log/resque-worker.log file which is extremely annoying because I don't know what is going on. It doesn't log anything in the syslog file nor the dmesg

This is a piece of what I get in the log (not helpful for me)

```
*** Starting worker workers:19166:*
*** Starting worker workers:19133:*
*** Running before_first_fork hook
*** Exiting...
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /data/www/tap-production/releases/20170904162514)
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
*** Running before_first_fork hook
*** Exiting...
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /data/www/tap-production/releases/20170904162514)
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
*** Starting worker workers:19251:*
*** Starting worker workers:19217:*
*** Running before_first_fork hook
*** Exiting...
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /data/www/tap-production/releases/20170904162514)
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
*** Running before_first_fork hook
*** Exiting...
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /data/www/tap-production/releases/20170904162514)
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
*** Starting worker workers:19330:*
*** Starting worker workers:19297:*
*** Running before_first_fork hook
*** Exiting...
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /data/www/tap-production/releases/20170904162514)
/usr/local/www/tap-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
```

Here's my resque.god.rb code:

```
require 'tlsmail'
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV']
rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT']
rake_root = ENV['RAKE_ROOT']
num_workers = rails_env == 'production' ? 6 : 1
# Change cache to my_killer_worker_job if you are testing in development. remember to enable it on config/resque_schedule.yml - Fabian
queue = rails_env == 'production' ? '*' : 'my_killer_worker_job'

God::Contacts::Email.defaults do |d|
  Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
  if rails_env == "production"
    #Change this settings for your own purposes
    d.from_name = "#{rails_env.upcase}: Process monitoring"
    d.delivery_method = :smtp
    d.server_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    d.server_port = 587
    d.server_auth = :login
    d.server_domain = 'gmail.com'
    d.server_user = 'XXXX@gmail.com'
    d.server_password = 'XXXX'
  end
end



God.contact(:email) do |c|
  c.name = 'engineering'
  c.group = 'developers'
  c.to_email = 'engineering@something.com'
end

num_workers.times do |num|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.name          = "resque-#{num}"
    w.group         = 'resque'
    w.interval      = 30.seconds
    w.env           = { 'RAILS_ENV' => rails_env, 'QUEUE' => queue, 'VERBOSE' => '1' }
    w.dir           = rails_root
    w.start         = "bundle exec #{rake_root}/rake resque:work"
    w.start_grace   = 10.seconds
    w.log           = File.join(rails_root, 'log', 'resque-worker.log')

    # restart if memory gets too high
    w.transition(:up, :restart) do |on|
      on.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
        c.above = 200.megabytes
        c.times = 2
        # c.notify = 'engineering'
      end
    end

    # determine the state on startup
    w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
        # c.notify = 'engineering'
      end
    end

    # determine when process has finished starting
    w.transition([:start, :restart], :up) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
        c.interval = 5.seconds
        # c.notify = 'engineering'
      end

      # failsafe
      on.condition(:tries) do |c|
        c.times = 5
        c.transition = :start
        c.interval = 5.seconds
        # c.notify = 'engineering'
      end
    end

    # start if process is not running
    w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = false
        c.notify = {:contacts => ['engineering'], :priority => 1, :category => "workers"}
      end
    end


  end
end
```

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: have you tried outputting some text at different places in your task to see if it is ever executed? Also, does this happen in production only?

Comment: Yes, it is executed because I can see the workers running the different jobs from time to time. And yes, it happens only in production.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i got to the bottom of the problem. On my routes file I had added a call to a method in order to load some dynamic routes and looks like resque didn't like it and just kept killing the processes without saying anything (still very weird). however, after removing that line (DynamicRouter.load) the workers stopped the crazy behavior. I hope this helps someone else and I'll be glad to give more details on what I could find.

Comment: Can you give some more details on the issue, I am facing the same issue in production server where workers are dying silently whenever I run a particular job, it runs fine in production though